# Flutter - How to open a folder previously created in gallery

Tags: flutter, dialog, gallery

I succesfully save an image to gallery using `save_in_gallery: ^0.1.3` package in my flutter project.

Once it's done I show a Dialog to ask the user if want to open the file.

How can I open `'Flutter Images'` folder from the 'Open' FlatButton?

(I need to open the folder because you can't name your image files in iOS, then i prefer the user open the folder and can see all the images that has saved)

```
await ImageSaver().saveImages(
        imageBytes: [pngBytes], directoryName: 'Flutter Images').then((onValue) {
      if (onValue) {
        showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Saved Completed'),
                content: Text('Do you want to open your file?'),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('Open'),
                    onPressed: () {}, //---> OPEN FOLDER FROM HERE <---
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('Close'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  )
                ],
              );
            })
```

---

`pngBytes` is the Uint8List that i actually save in `'Flutter Images'` folder inside the gallery.

---

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://pub.dev/packages/open_file library to open any file from storage.

`OpenFile.open("path_to_file_here");`

**For example**

`OpenFile.open("/sdcard/Flutter Images/image.png");`

Comment: I have read that you can't name image files in iOS, then i can't open a file because i don't know the name of file hen i save it. Then i actually need to open `'Fultter Images'` folder instead the file, do you know how to achieve that? Thanks for your answer.